# How can I use google analytics without Global Site Tag?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm building web-based crypto wallet and I want to track very basic info, such as wallet get created event. However I don't want to use Tracking code, Global Site Tag (gtag.js). Is there any way to send info to analytics from my web-app without tracking code? 
Something like this:

```
Axios.post(
   "https://analytics.google.com/....", 
   data : {"event" : "new_wallet_created"}
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can send by a get request

```
url: www.google-analytics.com
method: GET
payload:{
 v:1, //this must be 1
 t:pageview, //hit type (pageview , event, social vs vs.)
 tid: UA-XXX, //your tracking id
 cid: xxxx //user id (this is randomly generated)
}
```

See the parameter list here:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters

Comment: I don't think it works correctly. I've sent a couple post requests on Postman and get 107.75 KB response.

Comment: It should be a get request, not a post request. Exp: www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-xxx-8&cid=414885936.1571048436&t=pageview @lebed2045